# Converting a parsing tutorial into a project

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I followed a tutorial on youtube to add parsing to an android app. In his tutorial he parsed data inside a record tag that never closed located at http://demoprojectserver1234.appspot.com/xmlquery.cgi?appid=3fa19507-c746-4dfa-8ded-ec60ef4d30d9.  I would like to apply this to my project and parse some of the google map api.  http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=Denver&destinations=Miami&language=en-EN&sensor=false from that url I would like to adapt the tutorial to capture the value of the duration text tag 1 day 5 hours as well as the distance text tag 3,317 km.

This is my main activity class right now after finishing the tutorial.  I know that I would need to change inside the processReceivedData method if (tagName.equals("record") to something but I am not sure if i would use duration or text, and I am not sure if I would make a second if (tagName.equals("record") to capture the the distant/text or if I used text I could just make it a loop to grab both of them.  Any help pointing me in the correct direction to collect the values I am after would be appreciated.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private static final String TAG = "ProjectServerDemo";

Button destination_next_button;
public final static String START_LOCATION = "com.google.gascalculator.START_LOCATION";
public final static String END_LOCATION = "com.google.gascalculator.END_LOCATION";
public static final String QUERY_URL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins="
                    + START_LOCATION + "&destinations=" + END_LOCATION
                    + "&language=en-EN&sensor=false";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    destination_next_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.destination_next_button);
    destination_next_button.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private void destination_next_buttonClick() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Vehicle.class);

    EditText startText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.startinglocation);
    EditText endText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.endinglocation);

    String startDestination = startText.getText().toString();
    String endDestination = endText.getText().toString();

    intent.putExtra(START_LOCATION, startDestination);
    intent.putExtra(END_LOCATION, endDestination);

    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.destination_next_button:
        destination_next_buttonClick();
        AsyncDownloader downloader = new AsyncDownloader();
        downloader.execute();

        break;
    }

}

private void handleNewRecord(String itemId, String data) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.informationTextView);
    String message = 
            textView.getText().toString() + "\n" +
            itemId + ": " + data;
    textView.setText("");
}

private class AsyncDownloader extends AsyncTask<Object, String, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
        XmlPullParser receivedData = tryDownloadingXmlData();
        int recordsFound = tryParsingXMLData(receivedData);
        return recordsFound;
    }

    private XmlPullParser tryDownloadingXmlData() {
        try {
            URL xmlUrl = new URL(QUERY_URL);
            XmlPullParser receivedData = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser();
            receivedData.setInput(xmlUrl.openStream(), null);
            return receivedData;
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        return null;
    }

    private int tryParsingXMLData(XmlPullParser receivedData) {
        if (receivedData != null) {
            try {
                return processReceivedData(receivedData);
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {

            }   

        }
        return 0;
    }

    private int processReceivedData(XmlPullParser xmlData) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        int recordsFound = 0;

        //find values in the xml records
        String appId = "";
        String itemId = "";
        String timeStamp = "";
        String data = "";

        int eventType = -1;
        while (eventType != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String tagName = xmlData.getName();

            switch (eventType) {
            case XmlResourceParser.START_TAG:
                //start of a record so pull values encoded as attributes
                if (tagName.equals("record")) {
                    appId = xmlData.getAttributeValue(null, "appid");
                    itemId = xmlData.getAttributeValue(null, "itemid");
                    timeStamp = xmlData.getAttributeValue(null, "timestamp");
                    data = "";
                }
                break;

            //Grab data text (simple processing)
            //Note this could be full xml data to process
            case XmlResourceParser.TEXT:
                data += xmlData.getText();
                break;

            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                if (tagName.equals("record")) {
                    recordsFound++;
                    publishProgress(appId, itemId, data, timeStamp);
                }
                break;
            }
            eventType = xmlData.next();
        }
        //handle no data available publish an empty event.
        if (recordsFound == 0) {
            publishProgress();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {

        if (values.length == 4) {
            String appId = values[0];
            String itemId = values[1];
            String data = values[2];
            String timestamp = values[3];

            handleNewRecord(itemId, data);

        }
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to store the current node you are in, so that you can write 'if current node is row.element.duration.value then parse text as duration value'.

You can do this like so:

```
private StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder();

// (...)

case XmlResourceParser.START_TAG:
    path.append('.').append(tagName);

case XmlResourceParser.TEXT:
    String node = path.toString();
    if ("DistanceMatrixResponse.row.element.duration.value".equals(node) {
        // parse duration value
    } else if ("DistanceMatrixResponse.row.element.distance.value".equals(node) {
        // parse distance value
    } // etc...

case XmlResourceParser.END_TAG:
    path.setLength(path.length() - tagName.length()); // remove tag name
    if (path.length() > 0)
        path.setLength(path.length() - 1); // remove trailing '.'
```